# Preloading Associations with conditions lambda failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting a NoMethodError when trying to preload a has_many association that includes a conditions lambda.

#### Here are my Models

```
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

Class CalendarDay < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :events, 
    ->(_day) { 
      where(
        user_id: _day.user_id, 
        deleted_at: nil
      ) 
    },
    autosave: false,
    foreign_key: :date,
    primary_key: :date, 
end
```

#### Load some CalendarDays and try and preload events.

```
days = CalendarDay.all.to_a

loader = ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader.new
loader.preload(days, :events)

#NoMethodError: undefined method `user_id' for nil:NilClass
```

It appears the pre-loader only works on relationships without a conditions lambda.

Anyone have any ideas? Is this a bug in the ActiveRecord::Associations::Preloader class?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to preload an association then you can use conditions, however you won't be passed the parent record (_day in this case) since it would be different for each of the day objects.

Activerecord needs to come up with one query to load all of the events and it doesn't know how to do that when the condition changes for each parent object ( the same is true when you include an association too if my memory is correct)

Comment: hmm, okay I guess this is sort of a use case for composite primary keys. I have manually setup preloading.

Comment: I think there is a gem for composite primary keys

Answer (score 0):

I fond a nice article describing how to manually preload. http://mrbrdo.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/manually-preloading-associations-in-rails-using-custom-scopessql/

#### Here is my preloading code.

```
collection = CalendarDay.all
dates      = collection.map(&:date)
user_ids   = collection.map(&:user_id)

events = Event.where(
  date: dates,
  user_id: user_ids
).to_a

collection.each do |record|
  association = record.association(:events)
  association.loaded!
  association.target.concat(

    #events.where(
    #  user_id: record.user_id,
    #  date: record.date,
    #  deleted_at: nil
    #)

    events.find_all { |e|
      e.user_id    == record.user_id &&
      e.date       == record.date &&
      e.deleted_at == nil
    }

  )
end
```

#### Results

```
#No preload code.  
Views: 1129.8ms | ActiveRecord: 409.8ms

#Cache active record relation then query for each day.
Views: 296.4ms | ActiveRecord: 198.6ms

#Run query and use find_by
Views: 290.2ms | ActiveRecord: 28.2ms
```

Comment: You're doing one query per CalendayDay - why bother eager loading at all?

Comment: It is not ideal, Creating the activerecord relation for events and using that to query improved the request time by 20%. I am going to change `events` to an array and then use find_all.